# Can you find me a fix for npm run dev?

Tags: php, laravel

When i do `composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "8.0"` into the terminal i creates the folder blog with the needed files and folders. After that i do `composer require laravel/ui` second `php artisan ui bootstrap` third `php artisan ui vue --auth`. Then i change the package.json to following.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14"
    }
}
```

After that i run `npm install&&npm run dev` the new package.json establishes me that i can install npm. `npm run dev` gives me this error down below. Please find a fix that works.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/egg/.npm/_logs/2021-06-06T06_47_26_810Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/egg/.npm/_logs/2021-06-06T06_47_26_854Z-debug.log
```

Comment: "_Then i change the package.json to following_" What exactly did you change there? (You can [edit] your question and paste relevant data there instead of in the comments)

Comment: npm install cross-env

Comment: fixes npm run dev

Comment: have you check npm and node version

Comment: The message says `There is likely additional logging output above.`.  Is there logging input above the point you pasted or is that all there is?

Comment: Yes i checked npm and node versio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the cross-env npm package.

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

It's listed in your dev dependencies, make sure to run npm install first.